# Calling of one controller from another

Tags: angularjs

While loading I am calling one controller, however I am using `ng-include` to import another HTML page in the main HTML page.

I want to call `ng-controller` of included page.(How to call a child controller from a parent controller using `ng-init`)

Comment: Generally speaking, if you're trying to call something in one controller from another, you should probably extract that logic to a service.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "call the controller". Child controllers prototypically inherit from parent scopes. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide -- scope hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies).

Comment: Another good explaination -- [AngularJS Wiki -- Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Answer (score 0):

You need not call it seperately. Just add 'ng-controller' directive on the 'ng-include' element and assign its controller as shown below:

```
<div ng-include="template.url" ng-controller="YourController"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have the parent Controller [broadcast an event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) that the child scope will register:

```
.controller("ControllerParent", [$scope, function($scope) {
    $scope.alertChild = function() {
       $scope.$broadcast("custom-event", data);
    };
});
.controller("ControllerChild", [$scope, function($scope) {
    $scope.$on("custom-event", function(event, data) {
        //do something with event
    };
});
```